# What makes a history-tagged question closed?

Tags: support, reopen-request, close-reasons

I love to read about computer history. There are many questions regarding history on SU and a history tag. Some of the questions are closed:

https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/history?sort=votes&pageSize=50

Most questions do well, however, some of them are closed. Closed questions are eventually deleted (at least from the public internet).

For example, some closed questions:

- [What is the origin of K = 1024?](https://superuser.com/questions/287375/what-is-the-origin-of-k-1024)
- [What was the highest number of floppy disks ever used for a product?](https://superuser.com/questions/52038/what-was-the-highest-number-of-floppy-disks-ever-used-for-a-product)
- [Intel Core 2 CPU](https://superuser.com/questions/273832/intel-core-2-cpu)
- [AMD CPU clones of Intel chips](https://superuser.com/questions/271437/amd-cpu-clones-of-intel-chips)

The auto-cited close reasons include that SU `expect answers to be supported by facts, references, or expertise`, and I don't see what's the problem with some questions as their answers exactly do that: cite references supported by facts...

What makes a history question a candidate for closing and how could one "rescue" them for reopening?

**edit** I'm asking this because I'm interested in how to ask a good history question.

Comment: Examples: 1. maybe. 2. Meh, polling. 3, 4 General reference. Also, Closed questions are **not necessarily** deleted.

Comment: @Sathya according to this answer http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5495/why-arent-more-questions-deleted   "Closed questions are either ready to be fixed, or just waiting to be deleted."

Comment: @barlop doesn't mean we'll be on a witch hunt to actively monitor closed questions & delete them

Comment: @Sathya obviously(though you might see deleting them like fixing broken windows http://meta.superuser.com/questions/7388/why-and-when-are-closed-questions-deleted), but my point was, that closed questions that haven't yet been deleted, are not in any kind of special category of closed question.  When you wrote "Closed questions are not necessarily deleted"  I'm just making the point that none are exempt from deletion(they don't have a right to exist like open questions seem to).